# How do I move an app entirely from an iPod to an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipod, data-transfer

I have a game I wanted to play on a different device, my new iPhone, but it isn't that new and I already have too much stuff on it to even reset it.

How do I move that app? And remember, no resetting.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the app again from the App Store under the Updates tab > Purchased and searching for its name.

Your data/progress in the app will not transfer unless:

- It uses iCloud for data storage and you are signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID on both devices, or it uses a developer-specific way of syncing to a cloud service
- You backup the iPod, reset the iPhone to factory settings and restore the backup

Otherwise, your progress in the game will be lost. There is no way to transfer data for a single app between devices.